# AngularJS ng-click is not working for some filtered (Search ) results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angular-filters, mouseclick-event

I have Filtered users, after filter some results came but 0 th result is getting click event, but others are not. and in some cases click event for results not firing. then I removed search text, before filtered Item is coming with all the users but it is not clickable.

I don't know why, Can I get what is the issue for this one, below is my code sample

```
<input type="text" class="search-presentation form-control" placeholder="Search by Advertiser name" ng-model="searchUserName">


<div id={{"propVal"+$index}} ng-cloak class="advCard"  ng-repeat ="userDetails in userList | filter: searchUser | orderBy:'firstName'" style="pointer-events:{{userDetails.active==0?'none':'all'}}; opacity:{{userDetails.active==0?0.5:1}}" >
    <div class="leftPanel" ng-mousedown="selectUser(userDetails, $index)">
        <div class="trash"><h4 class="advName">{{userDetails.firstName}}   </h4></div>
    </div>
</div>


$scope.searchUser = function(user) {
    var re = new RegExp($scope.searchUserName);
    return re.test(user.firstName);
};

$scope.selectUser = function(selectedUser) {
    alert("hello" + selectedUser.firstName)
};
```

Comment: because you have `pointer-events: none` conditionally?

Comment: click event is not firing because in some cases `userDetails.active` is coming as 0 and because of this you are setting `pointer-events: none`

Comment: Hi tanmay and @Prateek Gupta, Thanks for your instant response, pointer-events: none, is not the problem I am facing, even I kept pointer-events: all. I am not getting click event. Is there any other mistake I made here ?

Comment: @SivaJ create a plunker to reproduce the issue